# Negate Word Groups? - Regular Expression (Regex)

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Its easy to get a regular expression that gets you ALL the "com/net/org"

Here it is:

```
^.+(com|org|net)$
```

BUT, I'm trying to find all domains that DON'T have a com/net/org

I can't seem to find a way to negate the word group com/net/org

Here are sample strings:

```
piquetraveldesign.com
rigall.com.au
hunt4me.co.uk
cialis-without-prescription.us
filipinocommunityseattle.org
mortgageplanningblog.com
mental-health-training.net
final-fantasy-xiv-gil.com
uoblife.com.sg
unashamedandassociates.biz
heaonlineshop.com
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Negative Lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!.*(?:com|net|org)$).+$
```

Comment: That worked amazing. Just curious why it doesn't work without the .+ at the end?

Comment: Because `(?!...)` is a zero-width assertion that only matches at the given positions.

Answer (score 0):

Since its fixed length you could use a *negative* lookbehind assertion.
If all the lines are in a single string, the multi-line mode must be set
so `$` means end of line, instead of end of string.

```
 # .+(?<!\.(?:com|org|net))$

 .+ 
 (?<!
      \.
      (?: com | org | net )
 )
 $
```